# Windows batch: Echoing non-literal string containing special characters

Tags: batch-file

### What I want to achieve

There are a few URLs comforming to a particular pattern. say

```
http://example.com/page1.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
http://example.com/page2.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
....
http://example.com/page999.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
```

Note there are special characters '&' in them.

I would like to generate this whole list with the following pattern

```
http://example.com/page(*).html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
```

and the `(*)` replaced with numbers `1,2,...,999`, and save it to a file (say list.txt). **No Quotes around the URLs are allowed.**

### My code and question

Firstly I tried with such code:

```
call :genlist "http://example.com/page(*).html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy" 999
exit /b

:genlist
:: given pattern abc(*), generate list abc0, abc1,abc2, ..., abc10, ... abc999 and save them to a file
:: parameters: %1 the pattern.
::             %2 the max number substituting the wildcard

set "patt=%~1"
( for /l %%i in (0,1,%~2) do @echo %patt:(*)=%%i %) >list.txt

exit /b
```

and failed due to the meta character '&', interpreted as a command connector rather than a normal character.

Then I tried enable-delayed-expansion:

```
 :genlist
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set "patt=%~1"
 ( for /l %%i in (0,1,%~2) do @echo !patt:(*)=%%i!) >list.txt
 endlocal
 exit /b
```

This fails due to some bad around the `%%i!)` that I do not understand.

And a third time, I tried quoting that to-be-echoed:

```
 :genlist
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set "patt=%~1"
 ( for /l %%i in (0,1,%~2) do @echo "!patt:(*)=%%i!") >list.txt
 endlocal
 exit /b
```

It works, but introduces unwanted quotes into the URL.

And I am in trouble that the to-be-echoed is a variable, not a literal string. If it were, I would be able to directly escape that ampersand.

What should I do?

Comment: To echo @amp; quote it as `^&`.

Comment: @Akina The problem is we don't know where the `&` is:   it is in a variable rather than a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I spotted the problem and solved it.

There are a few special characters that I forgot to escape.

`!patt:(*)=%%i!` should be `!patt:^(^*^)=%%i!`.

And since it's delayed expansion, `(0,1,%~2)` should also be `(0^,1^,%~2)`.

So the code should be:

```
:genlist
:: given pattern abc(*), generate list abc0, abc1,abc2, ..., abc10, ... abc999 and save them to a list file
:: parameters: %1 the pattern.
::             %2 the max number substituting the wildcard.

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "patt=%~1"
( for /l %%i in (0^,1^,%~2) do @echo !patt:^(^*^)=%%i! ) >list.txt
endlocal

exit /b
```

By the way I have written a piece of JScript code that does the same thing.

```
/* JScript: take a pattern of abc(*) and generate a list of abc0,abc1,abc2,...,abc999 
arg1: the pattern
arg2: the max number(not the count)

e.g.  
    cscript /nologo thisscript "http://example.com/page(*).html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy" 5

will write to stdout:

http://example.com/page0.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
http://example.com/page1.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
http://example.com/page2.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
http://example.com/page3.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
http://example.com/page4.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
http://example.com/page5.html?arg1=xxx&arg2=yyy
*/

with (WScript) {
    var pattern = Arguments.Item(0);
    var max_ind = Arguments.Item(1);

    for (var i=0; i<=max_ind; i+=1)
    {
        Echo (pattern.replace(/\(\*\)/g, i));
    }
}
```